# Как реализовать систему просмотра изменений на странице конкретным пользователем?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

есть простой сайт php и mysql , пока только в голове )
нужно реализовать функци сохранения изменений, например как в гугл документах, видно кто, что и когда менял
как это проще всего сделать?

Comment: Делаешь авторизацию по логин\пароль и вот

Comment: @Nilsan ну если подразумевается что и анон может менять некую сущность, то и авторизация не нужна. Я бы сделал так: кроме основной таблицы сущности,  дополнительную таблицу, в которую бы писал изменения при сохранении в основную таблицу.

Comment: а можно конкретнее? Например я изменил запись в какой то таблице/странице , если я авторизован, как мне затем выдать типа историю изменений на странице ? Например жму "история версий" , это надо по дате,времени,пользователю смотреть что он изменил и где конкретно, чтоб например подчеркивалось каким нибудь цветом...

Comment: @StereoFlo _видно кто, что и когда_ если можно анонимно то я думаю пункт "кто" тогда бы стоило убрать.
Павел, при изменении страницы\таблице просто пишите в БД например логин человека и timestamp. Потом делаете вывод просто. Почитайте как вывести данные из БД и записать